# Elementary OS does not work with NVIDIA (SOLVED)

Tags: nvidia, user-interface

I just completed the installation of Elementary OS on my desktop dell XPS 8920.
During the installation I noticed that the graph was a little bad, but I thought that after the installation it could hit some driver problem. However, after installation the system will not charge, a flashing dot will appear on the screen.
Searching a little more, I realized that this problem occurs in the new ubuntu, and it seems to me that there was no effort by the ubuntu community to solve this problem in the new version of the system.

My video card is a NVIDIA GFORCE 1050TI 4GB.

Does anyone suggest a solution? Or at least elementary developers can solve this?

Thank you,

Comment: it was a little hard to unbeatable what exactly is happening. laptop doesn't charge? flashing dot? can you add screenshot / image of what you see and explain more accurately what is happening

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment!The point is that the operating system when starting most of the time the screen of the monitor turns black, without visualization. And when with several attempts it is only with an intermittent point in the upper left corner.

The problem is an incompatibility of the Ubuntu system with the NVIDIA® GTX 1050 Ti 4GB Video Card. Searching the internet is possible to realize that this is a problem not solved by the ubuntu community and those who use it as a base, in the case of elementary.

I use a desktop dell XPS 8920 desktop.

Comment: Do you have any other card? I suspect that you are running the default open source "nouveau" driver which might not be supporting this card. can you boot in command line?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by downloading the video driver on my windows, I went into ubuntu recovery mode and installed the driver via USB.

No other tutorial worked, because the commands did not work because of dependencies!

Thank you!

Comment: (you can mark the answer as solved with the little check mark next to it) 